# Meteor 1.3 module structure

Tags: node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6

We all know that in Meteor 1.3 we get new package structure (?)
There are few tutorials on how to get started with meteor 1.3, for example:
https://voice.kadira.io/getting-started-with-meteor-1-3-and-react-15e071e41cd1

But I can not find how to get started with new modules. Make it isolated, import it. How my application structure should look like after all?

What I realise so far, is how to use existing npm modules:

`npm init -f`

and then install modules and import in my code like this:

`cloudinary = Npm.require("cloudinary")`

What if I want to use my own modules to break my application on parts like I used to do with `meteor packages`? Where to store it and how to create?

Comment: In 1.3 you can use ES2015 syntax to import from NPM modules and install them using `npm install`. Regarding your own modules, see [this document from MDG](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release-1.3/packages/modules/README.md).

Comment: This new module architecture precisely aims (with many other things) to break this way of building apps. It gives a horseload to load client-side and has not so many benefits aside controlling your load-order. When your app begins to have many files, you'd better go with lazy loading and importing only what you need rather than loading everything in the global scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `Npm.require` any more in 1.3. By default now (1.3-beta.8+) you can just import from any NPM module after you've `npm install`ed it:

```
import something from 'npm-module'
```

To organize your code, just organize it any way you want. There's no specific structure required. For example, if you have this structure:

```
main.js
folder/
  foo.js
```

then the files might be like

```
// main.js
import something from 'npm-module'
import foo from './folder/foo'
console.log(foo)
```

and

```
// folder/foo.js
let foo = 'hello'
export default foo
```

That's all there is to it (and assuming you wish to use ES6 Module syntax instead of CommonJS). The CommonJS version would look like this:

```
// main.js
let something = require('npm-module')
let foo = require('./folder/foo')
console.log(foo)
```

and

```
// folder/foo.js
let foo = 'hello'
module.exports = foo
```

Comment: Thank you! What about folders like client and server? Are they still valid?

Comment: Yep, still valid, as 1.3 is backwards comaptible with 1.2. :}